# Counting Number of times Item Appears in Structured List in Scheme

Tags: scheme, structure, racket

For reference I am programming in `Scheme` using `DrRacket`.

I am trying to count the number of times a name (string) is the first choice in a list of votes, but cannot seem to figure it out.

For some context of the problem,

A vote consists of the names of the three candidates that one person has voted for. This is defined as the structure: (define-struct vote (choice1 choice2 choice3)).

The function top-votes-for is supposed to consume a name and a list of votes and produces the number of times that the given name was the first choice vote in the list of votes.

This is my code (note the definition is incorrect):

```
;; Data Definition
(define-struct vote (choice1 choice2 choice3))
;; A vote is a structure: (make-vote String Number String). 
;; interp. 3 candidates that one person has voted for (String) 

(define vote1
  (make-vote "Blake" "Joey" "Will"))

(define vote2
  (make-vote "Blake" "Bob" "Ash"))

(define vote3
  (make-vote "Bob" "Ash" "Blake"))

(define listofVotes
  (list vote1 vote2 vote3))

;; Signature: top-votes-for: string list-of-strings -> number
;; Purpose: Consumes a name and a list of votes and produces the number of
;;          times that the given name was the first choice vote in the list of votes.
;; Tests:
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Blake" empty) 0)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Blake" listofVotes) 2)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Bob" listofVotes) 1)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Ash" listofVotes) 0)
;; Define:
(define (top-votes-for cand alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? alov) 0]
    [(string=? (vote-choice1 cand) cand) 1]
    [else ((first alov) (top-votes-for (rest alov)))]
    )
  )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `top-votes-for` is wrong. Here's a skeletal version of a corrected solution:

```
(define (top-votes-for cand alov)
  (cond ((empty? alov) 0)
        ((string=? (vote-choice1 <???>) cand)
         (add1 <???>))
        (else (top-votes-for cand (rest alov)))))
```

I've actually given you most of a solution. The rest of it should be easy to figure out, if you understand the code above.

Comment: I would think "cand" and "alov" would fit those ??? parts (in that order), but that seems to be not the case... @chrisj

Comment: Think harder. Hint: each of those `<???>` is a whole expression, not just a single variable. The first one has the shape `(<???> <???>)`, and the second one has the shape `(<???> <???> (<???> <???>))`.

Comment: Hmm. The first <???> is definitely `(vote-choice1 (first alov)) cand)` I think, but I'm not so sure about the second <???>. Perhaps something along the lines of `(add1 top-votes-for (rest alov))`? @Chris @ChrisJester @ChrisJester-Young

Comment: Correct re the first `<???>`. As for the second one, why would you call `add1` twice? Think about what you're adding 1 to. Hint: Think about what happens in the `else` case, then think about what you're doing differently in the `string=?` case.

Comment: ah alright, so it would be `(add1 (top-votes-for cand (rest alov)))`. Well, at least my check expects are coming out correctly. Thanks for the help! @Chris @ChrisJester @ChrisJester-Young